# Can functions be passed into functions and then called?

Tags: functions, notation

In computer science there are what are known as [higher-order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function). This means pretty much nothing, really. It is a property of a programming language.

I want to know if they are valid in mathematics, and if so, what the notation is. It would be like the following function definition:

$$g(x,y,f) = 20 + f(x + 3y)$$

The function itself is not really important. I just obscured it enough so that it cannot be made into a function composition.

I know that integrals, limits, and derivatives are sort of like functions that take functions as arguments. What about functions that return arguments?

Like:

$$h(f) = 3 \cdot f$$

The above would return the f function but where the terms are multiplied by three. Of course this would be f itself, not its image.

What is the difference between a function and its image anyway? I imagine it would be like the difference between source code and return values, but I have never heard of math having "source code" so it seems bizarre to me.

Comment: What you are looking for is called function composition and yes, you can compose all kinds of functions.

Comment: This fine and the notation is fine.  You just need to keep in mind that functions need a domain (input space) and a range (output space).  These need not be numbers.  The set of all real valued functions is notated as $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$ so the domain of this function is $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times \mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$ and the range is just $\mathbb R$.  So this is notated $g:\mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times \mathbb R^{\mathbb R}\rightarrow \mathbb R$.

Comment: The image of a function is only the output.  The function is the ordering of the input paired to the output.  So if $f:R -> R$ (say f(x) = x+2.) then the function is a set of ordered pairs:  Technically $f = \{(x,x+2)| x \in \mathbb R\} \subset \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$

Comment: @fleablood Thinking of functions as ordered pairs leads to loss of information about the codomain.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo So how would you write fleablood's second post?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo How so?  The codomain is the collection of second terms of the ordered pairs.  Personally I *hate* thinking of functions as ordered pairs (very unintiutive) and like think of the as "rules" that map (but very inaccurate and incomplete) but I can't deny the the  usefulness of ordered pairs model.

Comment: Oh, didn't see your "return function" part.  And g(sin) = 3.sin.  Nothing wrong with that.  The range/codomain would be the set of functions (perhaps you are assuming the set of real value to real value function but it doesn't even need to be that... well it as to be the set for functions that return real or complex values other wise 3.f doesn't make sense)  A function may map *any* set to *any* set, include the set of functions.  This is actually well-defined and quite common.

Comment: @fleablood If we are given the graph of $f$, $\{ (x,f(x)) \mid x \in \mbox{Dom}_f\}$, we can find the domain and the range via projection. What about the codomain? The codomain is given in the definition of a function, but not in its graph. The range is given by the projection of the graph, but not in its definition. Any set that contains the range could serve as the codomain.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo that's true but I don't see that has anything with "thinking of functions as ordered pairs"  If I say $f(x) = x + 2$ or $f = \{(x,x+2)\}$* neither* define the codomain and both are informal incomplete definitions.  It's implied domain is R and codomain is R.  A proper definition includes domain but a clunky f:R->R;f(x) = x+2 or f = {(x,f(x))} subset R x R both do.  You are right that the set of ordered pairs is a "graph" rather than the function but they are equivalent.    However my comment was due to my misinterpretting the OP's "what is the image"

Comment: @fleablood One can create an equivalence class such that two functions are equivalent if they have the same graph. Writing that the graph is a subset of the Cartesian product of the domain and the codomain gives the information about the codomain that is absent in the graph of the function. It's also a matter of taste. Sets are nouns, functions are verbs. Some like nouns more, others like verbs more.

Comment: Why are we having this discussion? I, like you, prefer verbs but I think when the op says, putting function as *input*?! and output!?  Can we *do* that?!?" than I think seeing it in terms of nouns then answer becomes a clear "sure.  Why not? Functions are just 'things' like everything else."  Functions as verbs... well it's a mental block to think of the range of a verbs.  You can't go to a farm and look at the pen of runs, or feed the free range subtractings.

Comment: @fleablood that last visual sounds like something out of a comedy skit. +1

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is perfectly valid, and there's no particular notation for it (the notation you used is perfectly fine).  In general, if $X$ and $Y$ are two sets then a function $g:X\to Y$ is a rule that assigns to each element of $X$ an element of $Y$ (more formally, "rule" here really means a set of ordered pairs $(x,y)$, where for each $x\in X$ there is a unique $y\in Y$ such that $(x,y)$ is in the set; we then say $y=g(x)$).  The sets $X$ and $Y$ can be any sets at all, including sets of functions.

So, for instance, your example $g(x,y,f)=20+f(x+3y)$ could be considered as a function whose domain is the set $X$ of all ordered triples $(x,y,f)$, where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function and whose range is $\mathbb{R}$.  Given any triple $(x,y,f)$, $g$ gives you a real number, namely $20+f(x+3y)$.

Answer (score 3):

Roughly speaking, in mathematics, **higher-order functions** come in two forms:

- [functionals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_(mathematics)) take functions and return **scalars**.
- [operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(mathematics)) take functions and return **functions**.

For example, the integral of a function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ over all $\mathbb R$ is a functional

$$I (f) := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f (x) \, \mathrm d x$$

Another functional would be the energy of a square-integrable function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$

$$\mathcal E (f) := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f (x)|^2 \, \mathrm d x$$

If I understand correctly, you are more interested in operators than in functionals. One can think of an electric circuit as an operator that transforms an input signal into an output signal. If this circuit has capacitors or inductors, then the operator will be a **differential** operator. For example, a simple RC circuit "embodies" the following differential operator

$$RC \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t} + 1$$

The gradient, divergence and curl are also differential operators. The indefinite integral is also an operator. The "source code" of an operator is its definition.

Answer (score 0):

This probably might fit more in a comment, but still.

You wrote:

> $$g(f)=3\cdot f$$
>   The above would return the f function but where the terms are multiplied by three.

And I want you to think a bit about it, because you have type mismatch here (using a programming jargon here as you have just revealed yourself being a programmer). You take a function, multiply it by a number and return it as a function.

As mathematics notation is meant to be understand by humans, which are *constantly* dealing with *disgustingly* ambiguous natural languages, chances are everyone is going to understand what you mean perfectly fine, *but*.

You cannot *really* multiply a number by a function (well, before you define such a thing). Assuming $f$ takes and returns a real number, which is notated as $$f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R,$$ then the usage of $3f(x)$, for example, is correct, as the part $f(x)$ means "the result of evaluation of $f$ at $x$", which we know is a real number, so multiplication by $3$ works.

However, the use of $3f$ **is problematic**, because, for one, $f$ might as well return something different from a number, as noticed by @fleablood. But, and *more importantly*, in this expression you have $f$ **unevaluated**.

And, rigorously speaking, that is not at all defined in usual *axiomatisations*. Calling something a number usually implies it is an element of some set on which there is a multiplication defined. And there isn't any *functions* in those sets (again, usually). For example, there aren't any in $\mathbb R$. So there isn't any readily available multiplication to use.

Functions and numbers are (usually thought of as) different things, and have different structure.

Additionally, the use of the word "term" is also problematic in your quote. There isn't any reason to believe some function was *defined via some formula*, which in turn *consists of terms*. Polynomials consist of terms. Other types of formulae may not. Furthermore, functions may be defined by a plot, a chart, a table of values, or simply described in English. Find a term to multiply by three there!

---

The plain fix would be the use of function definition notation:
$$g(f)=x\mapsto3f(x).$$
Notice the variable $x$ here is **local** and does not leave the scope of $\mapsto$. Better yet would, though, to specify the scope and domain, however you like. Maybe like
$$g(f)=\mathbb R\ni x\mapsto3f(x)\in\mathbb R$$
or
$$g(f)=x\mapsto_{_{\mathbb R\to\mathbb R}}3f(x).$$
Notice also, however, the difference between $\mapsto$ and $\to$. The former specifies *which element* maps to *which another element*, while the latter specifies *which sets* does the function relate.

---

P. S. **Please** do not use conflicting definitions (that's the second most irritating thing for me after sloppy use of function notation). Please notice you have $g$ defined twice and incompatibly in your original post.

Comment: G is just a couple of examples. I see no reason why it is "conflicting". It's clear from the context that it is two different gs.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck because I was going to refer to your first, and then second $g$ example, but could not, because they have the same name.

Comment: By the way, I fixed it.

Comment: Also, I never considered the undefinedness of multiplying a function by a number. Thanks.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck crap, now it's other way around and my post does no longer match your names! See what I mean? Anyways, you are very welcome! :)